# Check one series value, change corresponding point colour in 2nd series

Tags: vba, excel

I have an automated pareto chart working well in Excel.

I want to change it to check if points in the cumulative percentage series have a value of less than 80% and colour the same number point in the count series if this is the case.

Tried this; doesn't throw any errors but also doesn't work.

I think it should be iterating through a list of values, checking if they are <80 then updating the point at the corresponding i in the count series.

```
Set percVals = paretoChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(percentSeries).Values
For Each i in percVals 
    If percVals(i) = <80 Then
        With paretoChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(countSeries).Points(i)
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,225) 
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,225)
        End With
    End If 
Next i
```

The "paretoChart" variable is set earlier in the code and is working fine throughout. 
I've tried without the 'with' statement. No difference.

There is a similar question comparing the two values across series, but I don't think I can adapt that to work here. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to SO and thank you for your question. It looks well formated.

Comment: If you put in your code as second line: `Debug.Print percVals` does it render any output?

Comment: Hmm. No, it's not. I've tried addressing at as ActiveSheet.ChartObject.etc and that doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Did you check the immediate window for it. Otherwise you could insert a messagebox like so: `MsgBox percVals`

Comment: Yes, I've been using the immediate window to debug various bits as I go.

Comment: And if you debug print the line `paretoChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(percentSeries).Values`

Comment: Nothing, even if I take out the variables I've set and stick with the standard indexing. Which is weird, because it's plotting that series. Is it normal for VBA to make your head hurt this much?

Comment: At times it can be. I'm coming up blank now.

Comment: and how about percVals(1).Value Does that yield anything?

Comment: Nope. I'm rapidly determining that the users can colour the data points themselves!